# What is the difference between echo * and echo $a0* where $a is a variable? Why the output of both the commands are same?

Tags: unix

Suppose I have a variable a=2. When I run echo $a0*, it gives the same output as echo *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **a0** was taken as variable name by shell ***not a***.it give the value nothing,because variable a0 was not set.

so the **echo $a0*** was expanded as **echo *** and * will expanded as "file name list in current directory" by shell. then this string was printed by echo.

check your command **echo $a0*** by set the variable **a0=2**, it gives  output **2***.
change your code with **echo ${a}0*** to get yours expected output as: **echo 20***